# How to hide pages from certain users in angular and php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm creating a website in which users can create some profiles.
All profiles must be open for viewing only to users that the creator has chosen. The others won't be seeing them.

Using angular, you can easily create pages using routes, so of each new page you will have something like:

```
www.example.com/profiles/profile/1
www.example.com/profiles/profile/2
www.example.com/profiles/profile/3
etc.
```

But, say, you own profile 1,2,3 you can easily view profile/4, profile/5 etc...

How can you implement a system that prohibits viewing, or allows to see less data than the access-granded users?

Thank you.

Comment: i assume you have some sort of user management system? list what they can access in a db there and check on every profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told, the answer should be server side. authentications should always be server side..

In your case, you need to query the database only once like you have done so far, actually the correct term will be just sending a http request to your api (as the http requests is doing the db queries). that http request should start by checking what kind of permissions you got and return the appropriate data (limited list of users, a specific user or an error that you don't have access to that specific content).

I hope it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

If using a database you can add a column `AccessRights`

0 = Basic

1 = Profile 1

2 = profile 1/2

etc

Different integers of `AccessRights` will let you access different things.

and to stop people with access rights 1 from accessing accessrights 3 material

```
 if ($Accessrights < 3)
{
 die("You Cannot View This");
}
```

it will be up to you to assign a variable for `$Accessrights` or something.

Hopefully this is something your looking for

Comment: So do I have to query the database on each page a user visits? Wouldn't that be too resourceful?

Answer (score 0):

So do I have to query the database on each page a user visits? Wouldn't that be too resourceful?

The access system that I want to create is something in the same vein as facebook.
You can see your pages and your friends pages, but you cannot see the private pages.
You can edit your profile, but not othe peoples profile.

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the user is viewing his own record or if he is allowed to view any record

$iUserType = USER_TYPE_ADMIN; // constant
$iUserId = 5; // this and user type can be stored in session after login

$iViewProfileId = 5; // this should come from the request parameters

```
if (($iViewProfileId != $iUserId) AND     (USER_TYPE_ADMIN != $iUserType)) {
    // error, user is not permitted to view the record
}
```